# Python: Assign value to DataFrame column elements based on comparison of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame as below:

[Desired DataFrame values for Quantile and Value columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C5QC.png)

I have two objectives.

1. Create a quantile for each category (a, b, c, etc.) and assign it to the value in the Quantile column.
2. Compare each row in the Score column to the corresponding Quantile value for that group. If it’s above 90th percentile assign to column Value the number 3, above 60th, assign the number 2 and so forth.

So far I have been able to create (in an inefficient way) the following but I’m sure there must be a way to make this more efficient:

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

conditions2 = (df['scaled_score']>=df['quantiles2']) & (df['scaled_score']<df['quantiles1'])
conditions3 = (df['scaled_score']>=df['quantiles3']) & (df['scaled_score']<df['quantiles2'])
conditions4 = (df['scaled_score']>=df['quantiles3'])

df['quantiles1'] = df.groupby([‘Group']).scaled_score.quantile(0.9)
dfr1 = np.where(df['scaled_score']>=df['quantiles1']  ,0.5,0)

df['quantiles2'] = df.groupby([‘Group']).scaled_score.quantile(0.7)
dfr2 = np.where(conditions2 ,0.35,0)

df['quantiles3'] = df.groupby([‘Group']).scaled_score.quantile(0.5)
dfr3 = np.where(conditions3,0.25,0)

df['quantiles4'] = df.groupby([‘Group']).scaled_score.quantile(0.4)
dfr4 = np.where(conditions4,0.15,0)

dtest1=pd.DataFrame(dfr1)
dtest2=pd.DataFrame(dfr2)
dtest3=pd.DataFrame(dfr3)
dtest4=pd.DataFrame(dfr4)
dftest = pd.concat([dtest1,dtest2]).groupby(level=0).max()
dftest = pd.concat([dftest,dtest3]).groupby(level=0).max()
dftest = pd.concat([dftest,dtest4]).groupby(level=0).max()

df.drop(['quantile'],axis=1)
del df[‘quantile’, axis=1]
dftest.index=df.index
Panel2 = df.join(dftest, on=df.index)
df[‘Value'] = dftest
```

Comment: Hiya! Do you have any reason to suspect there is a more efficient way? What do you feel is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I will do `qcut`

```
s=df.groupby('Value').apply(lambda x : pd.qcut(x['scaled_score'],[0,0.5,0.7,0.9,1],labels=[0.15,0.25,0.35,0.5])).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df['New']=s
```

Comment: Explanation please @WeNYoBen